# how to convert WIF key return to HEX format

Tags: private-key, python, wallet-import-format

any one knows how to convert WIF key return to hex format please also let me know if the private key is out side range of ecc then how to import it to some wallet ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [this](https://github.com/mcdallas/cryptotools) python library (I am the author)

```
>>> from cryptotools import PrivateKey

>>> prv = PrivateKey.from_wif('5KUkQNKHA9cVmhSyKuNmop7r83DN2fMhPtNUW843Q6JxqRddEVz')
>>> prv.hex()
'db07a0c6c98c7a2b5cdc19cd4431a05908a40424d6d1ff20eac9cb2f9488e12d'
```

If the key is too large

```
>>> PrivateKey.from_int(1 << 260)
```

it will throw an error

```
AssertionError: Key larger than Curve Order
```

Comment: thank you mike is there any way to import the private key which fall out of range of elliptical curve

Comment: No. If you have a number that's too large you should first find it's congruent modulo N and then import that

Answer (score 0):

There is also a bash (or zsh) shell script to convert from WIF to hexadecimal format: https://gist.github.com/GregTonoski/fbe2740391a366add4bfcefded00c5c4

Simply run the script like in the example:

```
$ bash Bitcoin_WIF_into_hex.bash "L3wB8ytuxNS3SPX2CJnHqK48Zzqj1AnayDTrJomvNPDxuKvHyvpT" > private_key_bitcoin.hex
```